# CKEditor shows me html code

Tags: django, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

I tried to use the CKEeditor for my django project but when i add a new item which uses this editor, I see the html code.

I used it like this :

My model :

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category')
    content = RichTextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    online = models.BooleanField()
```

my url : `url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor.urls')),`

my view :

```
def view_post(request, slug):
    return render_to_response('website/view_post.html',
    {
        'post': get_object_or_404(Article, slug=slug),
    },
    context_instance = RequestContext(request)
)
```

and my template :

```
<div id="post">
    <h1> {{ post.title }}</h1>
    <p>{{post.content}}</p>
    <i>{{post.date}}</i>
</div>
```

Please help.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this in your template:

```
<div id="post">
    <h1> {{ post.title }}</h1>
    <p>{{post.content|safe}}</p>
    <i>{{post.date}}</i>
</div>
```

Comment: Osm...Thanks @otavisoares